# What is the brightest light?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

I have been to wikipedia about intensity of light, and there are at least 20 different ways to classify it. So I guess it boils down to the formula E = hf, which is the energy of a single photon. Now past gamma rays, is there a maximum frequency, hence energy of a photon? How does what we can create in labs compare to what exists in outer space?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a trivia question that doesn't seem to relate to physical principles.

Comment: We aren't to discuss physical phenomena in isolation? Without observation we may as well be mathematicians. Seems not fully rational(ised).

Comment: In regards to the last question, it's a fairly easy Google search away (e.g., see [this PBS article](http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/blogs/physics/2014/07/the-astronomical-particle-colliders-that-put-our-own-to-shame/)).

Comment: Also, the first question is a dupe of [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/159922/25301).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll suggest GRB 110918A, which had a peak luminosity of $L_{iso} = 4.7 × 10^{47}$ Watts. That a ten to the forty-seven - it isn't a typo.

Comment: If E = hf, can you calculate the frequency from this em source?

Comment: No becaue it wasn't a single photon.

Comment: To put this answer in an intuitive perspective, our Sun is a bit too light to ever go supernova, but if it did, then its explosion a hundred million miles away, here on Earth would be a billion times brighter that a hydrogen bomb exploding next to one's face.

Comment: JMLCarter --- Is there a maximum frequency of a photon? And how does this relate to Wattage?

Comment: Not really. Although it gets complicated, here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/341456/what-is-the-maximum-temperature-for-a-photon
This question is on hold now.