# What is the highest possible energy of a photon?

Tags: energy, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, frequency

Are following suggestions ok to cap the energy of a photon?

- When the photons have enough energy in a small enough volume to collapse into a black hole
- When the wavelength of the photons becomes the smallest possible. That is, some unit of space is indivisible and fundamental.

Comment: Your first point overlooks the fact that there is not necessarily a limit to the mass of a black hole.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there any theoretical limits on the energy of a photon?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/159922/)